# Can Kuhn's theory outlined in The Structure of Scientific Revolutions be applied to sociology? If not, what are the implications of this for sociology

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-method, philosophy-of-history, kuhn, philosophy-of-social-sciences

Can Kuhn's theory outlined in 'The Structure of Scientific Revolutions' be applied to sociology? If not, what are the implications of this for sociology?

Comment: Kuhn's key concept is that of [paradigm](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/60613/are-paradigms-still-the-driving-force-of-scientific-revolution) and the related on of *normal science*. Sociology has many theories (see e.g. [Max Weber](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/weber/)) but, in my opinion, no paradigm in Kuhn's sense.

Comment: There is a field of [sociology of science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociology_of_scientific_knowledge) that applies Kuhn's conceptions to all sciences, sociology itself included. For such sociology of sociology adaptation see e.g. [Harvey, The Use and Abuse of Kuhnian Paradigms in the Sociology of Knowledge](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0038038582016001009).

Comment: thank you so much!